# Null Pointer Exception when starting intent

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner in android and trying to make a simple application of my own. I have tried to post as much as detail of the code.

When i click the Show Task Button in `MainActivity.java`, it won't start the new Intent and throws the `NullPointerException`. If I remove the `setOnClickListener` and code related to it in `TaskList.java`, new Intent will start but buttons will not work. I have posted the logs to make it easy.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.budthapa.unsavedchanges;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button addTask;
    private Button cancel;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button showTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();

        addTask.setOnClickListener(this);
        showTask.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void initialize() {
        addTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
        showTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowTask);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();

        // cancel button works only if textbox is not empty
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAddTask:
            // call method that add tasks
            if (text.isEmpty()) {
                // if no content in the textbox
                Toast showMessage = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Please fill some task to add", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                showMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                showMessage.show();
            } else {
                addTask();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.btnShowTask:
            // It will start a new activity to show the list of task
            Intent showTaskList = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskList.class);
            startActivity(showTaskList);
            break;
        case R.id.btnCancel:
            // call this method when user creates cancel button
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                // there is some content in the text box
                unSavedDialog();
                break;

            }
            // you can call this code instead, but will not so any warning
            // finish();
            exitAppDialog(); // this code will show alert dialog box
        }
    }

    private void addTask() {
        // add new item to the array list
        String taskName = editText.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> taskArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        taskArr.add(taskName);
        // notify user that new task is added
        Toast addNewTask = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "New Task Added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        addNewTask.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        addNewTask.show();
    }

    private void exitAppDialog() {
        // this method will start when user clicks cancel button
        AlertDialog.Builder exitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        exitDialog.setTitle(R.string.exitApp);
        exitDialog.setMessage(R.string.exitMessage);
        exitDialog.setCancelable(false);

        exitDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // exit the app
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        exitDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        // cancel and return to the app
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = exitDialog.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private void unSavedDialog() {
        // this dialog will appear when user press cancel button
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.alertTitle);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.alertMessage);
        alert.setCancelable(false);

        alert.setNegativeButton("Add Task",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // save the task and exit
                        addTask();
                    }
                });

        alert.setPositiveButton("Discard Changes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // finish the activity
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // cancel the dialog box and return to the view
                arg0.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**TaskList.java**

```
package com.budthapa.unsavedchanges;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TaskList extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button addNewTask;
    private Button cancel;
    private TextView taskList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task_list);
        initialize();

        addNewTask.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addNewTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        taskList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void showTask() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCancel:
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(TaskList.this);
            alert.setTitle("Do you want to exit?");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

            alert.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            arg0.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;

        case R.id.btnAddTask:
            Intent showMain = new Intent(TaskList.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(showMain);

            finish(); // finish the current running activity and go back to main
                        // Activity
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: @Selvin  E/AndroidRuntime(11060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11060): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.budthapa.unsavedchanges/com.budthapa.unsavedchanges.TaskList}: **java.lang.NullPointerException**
E/AndroidRuntime(11060): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
E/AndroidRuntime(11060): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
E/AndroidRuntime(11060): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this..

there are two same btns

```
addNewTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
```

**TaskList.class**

task_list.xml don't have `btnAddTask` that why that error

You need to give xml btn id for different name for different activity

Comment: But, if these IDs don't exists, that should not cause a compiler error?

Comment: @angel_navarro btnAddTask is already exist in activity_main.xml then btnAddTask must not give that name to other actvity.xml if it gives it'll make NPE.

Comment: Ahh ok @Tamilan, thans for your clarification ;-)

Comment: Thanks it helped. Actually I was thinking if I can use same button.

Comment: @budthapa No, we need to use different id name for different activity it's link we are giving different name for layouts like that..

Comment: @budthapa if my ans really helpful ple accept it.

Answer (score 0):

//MainActivity.java

```
case R.id.btnCancel:
            // call this method when user creates cancel button
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {

                unSavedDialog();
                break;

            }

            exitAppDialog(); // this code will show alert dialog box
         break;   <------- MISSING......
        }
    }
```

Comment: That "case" is the last on that "switch()", so that will not have effect